# как рисовать анимацию поверх ранее нарисованной

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

уже несколько раз задавал вопрос, возможно неправильно, но решения не нашел. Очередная попытка)
Я создаю рисовалку. Мне необходима возможность рисовать произвольные линии, типа карандаш, и различные геом. фигуры при движении пальца(фигуры меняют свой размер в зависимости от отдаления от первоначального касания). С карандашем проблем нет, а вот при отрисовки геом. фигур возникает проблема, для анимации изменения размера я закрашиваю весь Canvas белым цветом, чтоб скрыть предыдущий размер фигуры, проблема в том что закрашивается все отрисованное до этого
Вот код:

```
public class Pencil {
private float x;
private float y;

private Path path;
private static Pencil pencil;
private Pencil(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x, y);
}
public static Pencil createPencil(float x, float y){
    if(pencil == null) return new Pencil(x,y);
    return pencil;
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
public void update(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    path.lineTo(x,y);
    }
}
```

```
public class Circle {
private float x;
private float y;
private float radius;
private static Circle circle;
private Circle(float x,float y, float radius){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}
public static Circle createCircle(float x, float y, float radius){
    if(circle == null) return new Circle(x,y,radius);
    return circle;
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint);
}
public void update(float startX,float startY,float finishX,float finishY){
    //AB = √(x2 - x1)2 + (y2 - y1)2 - расчет длины отрезка между точками
    double xInPow = Math.pow( (finishX - startX),2);
    double yInPow = Math.pow( (finishY - startY),2);
    radius =  (float) (Math.sqrt(xInPow + yInPow))/2;
}
}
```

```
public class ViewCanvas extends View {
private Bitmap mainBitmap;
private Bitmap saveBitmap;
private Canvas mainCanvas;

private Paint paint;

public ViewCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ViewCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ViewCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    saveBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mainCanvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);

    createDefaultPaint();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(saveBitmap,0,0,paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mainBitmap,0,0,paint);

    invalidate();
}
public void saveBitmap(){
   saveBitmap = mainBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
}
private void createDefaultPaint(){
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public Canvas getCanvas() {
    return mainCanvas;
}


public Paint getPaint() {
    return paint;
}

public void setBrashStyle(Paint.Style style){
    paint.setStyle(style);
}
public void setBrushColor(int color){
    paint.setColor(color);
}
public void setBrashWidth(float width){
    paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
}
```

}

Часть класса в котором происходит вся работа

```
 float startX = 0;
float startY = 0;
private boolean viewOnTouchListener(View view, MotionEvent event){
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    float radius = 0;

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
            if (currentTool == pencil) new Pencil(eventX,eventY);                
            if (currentTool == circle) new Circle(eventX,eventY,radius);
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
            drawCurrentTool();
            updateCurrentTool(eventX,eventY,startX,startY,event.getX(),event.getY());
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
            binding.paintView.saveBitmap();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void drawCurrentTool(){
    if (currentTool == pencil) pencil.draw(binding.paintView.getCanvas(),
                                                                     binding.paintView.getPaint());
    if (currentTool == circle) circle.draw(binding.paintView.getCanvas(),binding.paintView.getPaint());
}
private void updateCurrentTool(float x, float y,float startX,float startY,float finishX,float finishY){
    if (currentTool == pencil) pencil.update(x,y);        
    if (currentTool == circle) circle.update(startX,startY,x,y);
}
```

Главная проблема как перерисовывать фигуру на отрисованном Bitmape ?

Answer (score 0):

написал свой метод сохранения и помогло

```
//Добавляем до одного Bitmap то что было нарисовано на другом Bitmap
private void addCopyToBitmap(Bitmap in, Bitmap out){
    for(int i = 0; i < out.getWidth(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<out.getHeight();j++){
            if(out.getPixel(i,j) != Color.TRANSPARENT){
                in.setPixel(i,j,out.getPixel(i,j));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

правда не знаю на сколько корректно решение